# Doing performant image updates

Tags: c#, wpf, image, caching, windows-phone-8

I have a messenger app on Wp8 (MVVM Light). People can create group conversations and assign images to that conversations. Those images are shown besides the conversation titles in the conversation overview, the conversation itself and also in the conversation details.

Those images are cached. It is a two layer cache using weak memory cache and also isolated memory cache. Members of the conversation group are allowed to change the images. They do that by uploading a new image to the server and sending a conversation-image-changed-message to the other group message.

Now I am looking for a performant and ellegant way to change all the images. I can receive those update-message and I can easily clear the cache, so if the image gets rebind, it loads the new image, but the problem is with the already bound-images in the view that are in my navigation back stack. When i navigate back, i do not want to reset all images in that view, but just the ones that are out-dated.

I currently, i bind the images dirctly, using a ImageSource that i retrieve from the cache. I am thinking about a kind of imagecontainer, that holds the imagesource, and having a globally imagecontainer-manager that keeps weak references of the container and provides a bindable property to the image source. everytime i receive an image update i check the container if it still holds an weak reference to that image and just raise a property change event on the image source property.

are there any other or better ideas or maybe libraries that already implemented something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience with such operations when doing Windows (WinRT, UWP) implementation for FFImageLoading library (https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading). You could also try it - it has transformations support (custom too).

Basically you don't want to use anything like `WriteableBitmap` because it forces you to use UI thread when doing some pixel/data updates. You want to use `byte[]` or `int[]` pixel data. After all pixel data manipulation you just simply convert it to WriteableBitmap.

Great helpers how to achieve that is here: https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx/  (BitmapContext class)

You can call WriteableBitmap.Invalidate() to notify that it's data changed. You could also use the same WriteableBitmap image for multiple views. It'll speed up things (it's exactly how FFImageLoading does it).

Answer (score 0):

You can try out  [JetImageLoader](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader) by [Artem](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin). there is a [blog post](http://rahulpnath.com/blog/windows-phone-series-image-caching-library-jetimageloader/) about this as well

Comment: Thanks for that. But i already know this library (my implementation is actually based on it), but it is not a caching problem it is more like a notify-all-views-that-an-image-has-to-get-rebound-problem.

Comment: Ok now i am trying to visualize the problem, your conversation image changed is sent to the whole group, which updates the cache for each member/client, and now only the changed image should be updated from the cache not the images of other conversations a member might have had and this occurs only in the page where you can see all the conversations ?

Comment: To make things easy, let's assume I only have on group conversation. I navigated from conversation overview, to the conversation, to the conversation details. All three views show the conversation image. Now somebody changes the image and the notification arrives.
Now i have to notify each view (the current one, and actually also the ones in my backstack, that the particular conversation image has changed), because the image does not get reloaded automatically. I could subscribe to same-sort-of-event in each view/viewmodel but that can get ugly.